# What is wrong in this ruby statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to do something when I am connecting to  my own server(local).
I found request.env from the website, so I am using that array to compare my IPs.

```
<%
if request.env['HTTP_HOST']!="127.0.0.1" 
     puts request.env['HTTP_HOST']
else
     puts "its Local!"
end 
%>
```

When I run above in rails3, I get nothing printed...
I am new to ruby&rails3..

Answer (score 12):

When you want output in the web page, use `<%= %>`, not `<% %>`. The output will be the return value of the expression, so you don't want `puts`.

```
<%= 
   if request.env['HTTP_HOST']!="127.0.0.1"  
     request.env['HTTP_HOST'] 
   else 
     "its Local!" 
   end  
%>
```

Note that you can also use the `local?` method instead of checking environment directly.

```
<%= 
   if request.local?
     "its Local!"
   else 
     request.env['HTTP_HOST']
   end  
%>
```

If you like conciseness you can do it as one line:

```
<%= if request.local? then "its Local!" else request.env['HTTP_POST'] end %>
```

For even more view conciseness, make use of a helper method:

```
<%= ip_or_local %>
```

where in the matching view helper you put:

```
def ip_or_local
   if request.local?
     "its Local!"
   else 
     request.env['HTTP_HOST']
   end  
end
```

For this simple case, it may be overkill but in general when you start seeing lots of code in your view, it's time to think about hiding certain things in helpers.

Comment: And with syntactic sugar: `request.local? ? "its Local!" : request.env['HTTP_POST']`.

Comment: @Yannis, I consider the ternary operator syntactic vinegar. :)

Comment: Is there anything like NOT operator that I can use with request.local? In PHP, if(!$a) means 'if not $a..' I was wondering if there is such thing in ruby.That way, I wouldn't need to write else statement.

Comment: @pavlo You mean `if not request.local?`

Comment: Just curious - should such printf-debugging be done in the HTML produced, or in the server logs?

Comment: I don't think the intent was debugging. He was trying to get conditional output in the web page.

Answer (score 4):

`puts` will write to the server in this case, not to the response. so you should look for your message in the log of the server.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but this answer doesn't solve the original question, i.e. "use <%= %> instead of <% %>".

Comment: the O.P. was interested why it didn't print anything. puts will never print output to the response, just to the log

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print to the log or to the view?

It might be clearer if you break things up into seperate erb tags.

```
<% if local? %>
  <%= "Text for local" %>     
<% else %>
  <%= "Text for remote" %>    
<% end -%>
```

You need to use <%= %> tags for lines you want printed and <% %> tags for lines that you want logic in, like conditionals.

If you're new to rails, you should check out the peepcode rails from scratch videos, they're pretty cheap and a lot of rails developers built their base on what's in them. Railscasts are also snack sized little tutorials that will easily get you through a lot of the basics.

Recommended reading:

RUBY:
The ruby pickaxe
The ruby way

Rails: 
The Rails way
Head first ruby on rails

Hope I was of some help.